# Regular Expression HTML Tag Exclusion

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

Yes, yes, I've weighed using an xml parser instead of regular expressions, but this seems to be a simplistic enough case that it's suitable:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

tempSite = 'http://www.sumkindawebsiterighthur.com'
theTempSite = urlopen(tempSite).read()
currentTempSite = BeautifulSoup(theTempSite)
Email = currentTempSite.findAll('tr', valign="top") 
print Email[0]
```

Currently results with:

```
<tr valign="top">
<td><p>Phone Number:</p></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><p>706-878-8888</p></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to remove all markup (tr, td, p,   would be nice too) and result:

```
Phone Number: 706-878-8888
```

My problem is over-exclusion AND multiple lines being regex'd, looking for an answer that outputs on a single line.

Comment: You don't need an XML parser if you already have a DOM with BeautifulSoup. Surely you can recursively iterate over the subnodes and concatenate the inner text of each? (I've never used BeautifulSoup)

Comment: I'm getting an empty list (`Email = []`), is that the correct URL?

Comment: Haha no, not the correct site. Keeping someones information private. THere's got to be a simple solution for this though.

Comment: +1 for @Cameron. Don't use regex for this, try a bit further with BeautifulSoup, you get a better result, and learn "the right way" to do this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your results are really always that simple, the following regex will put 'Phone Number:' in capture group 1 and the number in capture group 2 as long as the `re.DOTALL` flag is set:

```
.*(Phone Number:).*?([-\d]+).*
```

You can then call `re.sub()` on your string with the replacement `\1 \2`.

Here is a complete example that returns what you want:

```
>>> s = """<tr valign="top">
... <td><p>Phone Number:</p></td>
... <td>&nbsp;</td>
... <td><p>706-878-8888</p></td>
... </tr>"""
>>> regex = re.compile(r'.*(Phone Number:).*?([-\d]+).*', re.DOTALL)
>>> regex.sub(r'\1 \2', s)
'Phone Number: 706-878-8888'
```